# Windows password notification for Ubuntu/Mac users

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, windows-server-2008-r2

So, I know in Windows Server you can set a GPO to notify "Windows Users" x amount days before their password expires. My question is, what's the best/simplest way to notify other platforms as well? At the moment, we use something call "Password Self Service" but it has never worked correctly and I want to get rid of it. It's more trouble then it's worth.

Any suggestions would be great, thank you!

Comment: The best I can do is google the same question. Would http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/grouppolicy.asp work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PowerShell script that is run by a scheduled service on a domain controller which locates all users whose passwords expire withing a certain time and **e-mails** each user a notification. Requirements of this solution include a recent enough version of PowerShell (2.0 or later might suffice), an SMTP relay server of some point, and e-mail address fields populated in AD for each user. The script must run with elevated privileges.

```
$from = "<administrator@example.com>"
$subject = "Your password on the domain example.com is expiring soon"
$smtpServer = "smtprelay.example.com"

$today = Get-Date

# An HTML formatted e-mail body has been created and saved to a text file.
# This command reads the file into an array, each array element is one line of the file.

$bodyArray = Get-Content -Path "C:\ScriptData\emailbody.txt"

# The e-mail command won't correctly send the array for the e-mail body, we have to convert it to a stream of text.

for ($i=0; $i -lt $bodyArray.Count; $i++) {
  $body += $bodyArray[$i]
}

# Regarding the dates in this next command, it's meant to get passwords
# expiring within seven days (that's where the 8 comes from) and exclude
# passwords that have already expired. In AD, numerical zero means 1/1/1600,
# but outside of AD numerical zero is 1/1/1, so 1600 years must be added to
# dates retrieved from AD to compare them to dates computed in PowerShell
# using Get-Date.

$expiringUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} -Properties "GivenName","samAccountName","EmailAddress","msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Where-Object {((Get-Date($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')).AddYears(1600) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(8)) -and ((Get-Date($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')).AddYears(1600) -gt (Get-Date))}

foreach ($user in $expiringUsers) {

  $timeRemaining = New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End (Get-Date($user.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')).AddYears(1600)
  $daystopassexpiry = $timeRemaining.Days

  # The next command replaces what I'll call constants in the e-mail body file
  # with the values retrieved from the user's AD information. This
  # personalizes each e-mail.

  $newbody = $body -replace "--GIVENNAME--",$user.GivenName -replace "--USERNAME--",$user.SamAccountName -replace "--NUMBER OF DAYS--",$daystopassexpiry -replace "--EMAILADDRESS--",$user.EmailAddress

  Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $user.EmailAddress -Subject $subject -BodyAsHTML -Body $newbody -SmtpServer $smtpServer

  $newbody = $null
}
```

I suggest adding error catching (`try/catch`) and if you do run it as a scheduled job, I like to add a logging facility using `Start-Transcript` so I can more easily figure out what went wrong. I also suggest adding a `-BCC` to the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet to yourself so you can make sure e-mails are getting through and are formatted correctly.

I created the e-mail body by crafting an e-mail that looked the way I wanted, with all the 'constants' written in, and then I sent it to myself, and then I viewed the e-mail source and copied that to a text file.